# VS code stopped recognizing my classes and idk why

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-studio

I'm a beginner dev and I have a class assignment which is making a WordPress site using a child theme customization (PHP/CSS/JS).

Here is the issue : for some reason that I've ignored, VS code is not recognizing the classes I use and they are the same ones that were working just fine before.

Here is the issue, you can tell some classes are in white instead of orange

```
.wp-block-button a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#7864f4, #00aeef);
  color: #fff;
  border-color: linear-gradient(#7864f4, #00aeef;
}

.wp-block-button a:hover:before {
  height: 200%;
}


/* end block button*/

/* menu hover */
.nav li:hover {
  color: #00aeef;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover {
  color: #00aeef;
}
```

If anyone has a solution for this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've missed a closing bracket in 4th line in the screenshot. Please paste your code next time instead of pasting a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a bracket on the fourth line. CSS requires you to have opening and closing brackets in these types of instances.

The code below should fix it:

```
.wp-block-button a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#7864f4, #00aeef);
  color: #fff;
  border-color: linear-gradient(#7864f4, #00aeef);
}

.wp-block-button a:hover:before {
  height: 200%;
}


/* end block button*/

/* menu hover */
.nav li:hover {
  color: #00aeef;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover {
  color: #00aeef;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code, click `View` then `Problems` for a list of problems in your source code. A web search for those problems will help solve much more significant errors.

The community has mixed feelings about homework questions.

We can show we value their time and help by describing our efforts to solve the problems ourselves. Example: "I googled `VS Code double-red underline`."

Line 4 of screenshot has a double-red underline indicating the spot of the syntax error:

```css
border-color: linear-gradient(#7864f4, #00aeef;
                                              =
```

There is a missing closing parenthesis character `)`:

```css
border-color: linear-gradient(#7864f4, #00aeef);
                                              =
```

Balancing parenthesis and other special syntax characters is one of the most common syntax errors across scripting and programming languages, you'll get used to watching for it.

For most IDE's like VS Code:

- When your cursor is on a parenthesis, most editors will also indicate the matching parenthesis.
- Highlight warnings and errors via underlining, highlighting, or other visual indications.

In this case, there should also be a red line in the code minimap, and a red dot on the scroll bar.